# An issue enabling a panel on event

Tags: c#

What I want to do now is have my program, in the background add up the 5 seconds after every occurrence such that once 25seconds have occurred an event is fired.

Any suggestions?

Here is some code of what is going on

```
        private void autoshapingPanel_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {

        }

        //Code for Peck Counter

        private int counter = 0;

        public event EventHandler Clicked5TimesEvent;

        private void OnClicked5TimesEvent()
        {
            if (Clicked5TimesEvent != null)
            {
                Clicked5TimesEvent(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            }
        }

        //Stimulus with Peck Counter
        private void pictureBox1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            counter++;
            if (counter % 5 == 0)
            {
                //Code for Hopper
                //Code to Write Data
                string file_name = "C:\\Users\\Carter Daniels\\DATA\\AUTOSHAPINGdata.txt";
                System.IO.StreamWriter objWriter;
                objWriter = new System.IO.StreamWriter(file_name, true);
                objWriter.WriteLine("5 pecks");
                objWriter.WriteLine("1 Reinforcement");
                objWriter.Close();
                //ITI Panel
                ITIpanel.Visible = true;
            }
        }

        private void ITIpanel_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            if (ITIpanel.Visible == true) 
            {
                ITItimers.Enabled = true;
            } 
        }

        private void ITItimers_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ITIpanel.Visible = false;
            string file_name = "C:\\Users\\Carter Daniels\\DATA\\AUTOSHAPINGdata.txt";
            System.IO.StreamWriter objWriter;
            objWriter = new System.IO.StreamWriter(file_name, true);
            objWriter.WriteLine("5s ITI");
            objWriter.Close();
            ITItimers.Enabled = false; 
            autoshapingPanel.Visible = true;
        }
    }
}
```

What i want my program to do is count the # of times the ITIpanel or ITItimers has occurred and fire a new event after one or the other, preferably the timer has occurred 20 times

Comment: What is this "red stimulus" you speak of? Perhaps posting some code will help make this question less confusing.

Comment: I added the code. What i want my program to do is count the # of times the ITIpanel or ITItimers has occurred and fire a new event after one or the other, preferably the timer has occurred 20 times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems a lot of text for a basic question - if I'm understanding it.  Just do another event similar to your existing one.

```
    private int _timerCounter = 0;
    private void ITItimers_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if( _timersCounter++ == 5 ) {
             OnTimerFired20TimesEvent();
             _timersCounter = 0;
        }

        ITIpanel.Visible = false;
        // ...
    }

public event EventHandler TimerFired20TimesEvent;

        private void OnTimerFired20TimesEvent()
        {
            if (TimerFired20TimesEvent != null)
            {
                TimerFired20TimesEvent(this, EventArgs.Empty);
            }
        }
```

Comment: I get an error that says: OnTimerFired20TimesEvent does not existr in this context.

Comment: Little too much hand-holding. Don't copy/paste code but actually try to understand. Added code above

Comment: Ok. Now I see the issue, and actually all of the stuff you just added I had added. However, for the If (etc...) I had OnTimersFired20TimesEvent instead of just TimerFired20TimesEvent, etc...